DTFT of an autocorrelation function is producing a complex PSD?
I'm trying to find the PSD of a pretty simple autocorrelation function for a discrete random process, $R_x[k]=\cos(ω_0k)$.
From a data-book for Z-transforms, $g_k =\cos(ω_0k)$ transforms into $$G(z)=\frac{1-\cos(ω_0)z^{-1}}{1-2\cos(ω_0)z^{-1}+z^{-2}}$$
I applied this then used the substitution $z=e^{jθ}$ to make it into the DTFT which in theory gives the power spectrum. However this is a complex spectrum which shouldn't be possible as the autocorrelation function is even. What am I doing wrong here?

Hi - I'm solving this analytically so not using code. The power spectrum above is complex because $S_x(e^{jω})$ becomes $\frac{e^{jω}-cos(ω_0)}{2cos(ω)-2cos(ω_0)}$ after multiplying by $\frac{e^{jω}}{e^{jω}}$

You should have looked up the DTFT instead of the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform. Or, if you know that $e^{jk\omega_0}$ transforms to $2\pi\sum_r\delta(\omega-\omega_0+2\pi r)$, you could have used
$$\cos(k\omega_0)=\frac12\left(e^{jk\omega_0}+e^{-jk\omega_0}\right)$$
to come up with
$$\textrm{DTFT}\big\{\cos(k\omega_0)\big\}=\\\qquad\qquad\pi\sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty}\big[\delta(\omega-\omega_0+2\pi r)+\delta(\omega+\omega_0+2\pi r)\big]\tag{1}$$
which has the expected property of being real-valued and non-negative.
The problem with the (bilateral) $\mathcal{Z}$-transform is that it doesn't exist for the even sequence $\cos(k\omega_0)$. What you found is the expression for the unilateral $\mathcal{Z}$-transform, which only considers indices $k\ge 0$. If you then replace $z$ by $e^{j\omega}$, you basically obtain the DTFT of $\cos(k\omega_0)u[k]$ (except for the Dirac impulses at $\pm\omega_0$), where $u[k]$ is the unit step sequence. Obviously, that sequence is not even, so it's no surprise that its DTFT is complex-valued.

We gotta be careful with this DTFT bizness, Matt.
$$\textrm{DTFT}\big{\cos(\omega_0 n)\big} \ = \ \pi \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(\omega-\omega_0 - 2\pi k)+\delta(\omega+\omega_0  - 2\pi k)$$
I think that whenever we say "DTFT" we gotta make sure that everyone understands it's periodic with period $2 \pi$.  That also solves the problem of how to express aliasing when $|\omega_0| \ge \pi$.

Also, if it were me, just to be consistent with O&S "scripture" and most expressions of the DFT/FFT, I would use "$n$" for discrete time and "$k$" for discrete frequency.

@robertbristow-johnson: I did add a note in brackets (for whom do you think? :), but you're right, in order to be completely and absolutely correct, without any chance of misunderstandings, I added the sums. As for the indices, we're not doing DFTs here, so there's no frequency index anyway. And note that O&S use $n$ for the time index, but not for time lags, as is the case for autocorrelations. They use $m$ and $\ell$ for that, so I think we're good with $k$.

Oh yeah, you're right.  I wasn't thinking autocorrelation.
